# Как сделать таблицу для каждого пользователя отдельным по id?

Tags: php, mysql

Всем привет, кто может помочь помогите? есть таблица заказов, как сделать эту таблицу для каждого пользователя отдельным? Например пользователь1 вводит какие-то данные и данные эти отображаются для всех пользователей, как сделать чтобы данные отображались в таблице только для пользователя1? (PHP)

Comment: выбирать из таблицы с условием на id пользователя.

Comment: спасибо, можно еще подробней пожалуйста?

Comment: Каков вопрос, таков и ответ. Нужно знать структуру таблицы, как вы сейчас к ней обращаетесь и в чем собственно проблема в выборке только нужных записей (вы же наверняка в sql запросе задаете какой то where ...)

Comment: [WHERE](http://oracleplsql.ru/where-mysql.html)

Comment: скажем я понял, что надо выбирать из таблицы с условием на id пользователя. mysqli_query($connect, "SELECT * FROM Users WHERE id = '$id'"); не могу понять как вывести эти данные которые ввел пользователь1 только у него на странице. (количество данных огромное поэтому не стал писать). есть две таблицы в mysql `Users` и `Things`. в users находятся пользователи в things находятся товары. Не знаю как вывести товары которые ввел пользователь только на странице в таблице заказов этого пользователя

Comment: связать таблицы FOREIGN KEY заюзать, а потом показывать где id будет id с таблицы

Answer (score 0):

Попробуйте реализовать свой запрос через оператор INNER JOIN, он формирует таблицу из записей Ваших двух таблиц. Каждая строка из первой (левой) таблицы Users, сопоставляется с каждой строкой из второй (правой) таблицы Things, после чего происходит проверка условия. Если условие истинно, то строки попадают в результирующую таблицу. В результирующей таблице строки формируются конкатенацией строк первой и второй таблиц.
Например:
SELECT * FROM Users INNER JOIN Things
ON Users.UserID = Things.ThingsID.
В данном запросе оператора INNER JOIN условие сравнения — это равенство полей UserID и ThingsID, где поле ThingsID являются внешним ключом и ссылаются на таблицу Users. 
Добавьте к запросу оператор WHERE UserID = '$id'.